# Is Newtons Law of cooling applicable for all forms of heat loss?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, radiation, convection, thermal-conduction

Can heat loss through Conduction, Convection and Radiation be explained by Newton's law of cooling?

Or it is just applicable for heat loss through Convection and Radiation?